# htaccess redirect fake folder structure

Tags: .htaccess

Trying to create fake folder structure.

Essentially what I want is any request to http://www.example.com/** (where ** equals any two letters) to redirect to http://www.example.com/folder/index.php?var=** (where ** equals the two letters from the first link)

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/folder/index.php?var=$1
```

This is what I have right now, but it isn't working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the leading `/` from the `RewriteRule`.  The expression matched on the left side should not begin with `/` as a `REQUEST_URI` would.  You can also omit the entire `http://example.com` from the right side, since you are rewriting on the same domain.

```
RewriteEngine On
# Rewrite 2 characters into var
RewriteRule ^(.{2})$ folder/index.php?var=$1 [L,R]
```

If it should match only alpha chars, it is recommended to limit the expression further (beyond `.{2}`, which matches 2 of *any* character)

```
# Only rewrite on exactly 2 alpha chars...
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z]{2})$ folder/index.php?var=$1 [L,R]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried both of your examples, but they don't seem to be working. I replaced my rewriterule with yours (the only change in my file). Is there something missing?

Comment: @jsquadrilla You have mod_rewrite.c installed? Try it also with `http://example.com/folger/index.php?var=$1 [L,R]` though it should not make a difference.